# When using Stackexchange Redis thousands of connections are being created

Tags: caching, redis, lazy-initialization, stackexchange.redis

We have just started using the Azure Redis Cache from web and worker roles. We have found that under fairly light use ~2.5K connections were created.

We are using the StackExchange.Redis nuget package wrapped in a connection manager

```
  public class RedisConnManager
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public RedisConnManager(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection
    {
        get
        {
            return new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(
                () => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(
                    this.configuration.SessionManagerRedisConnectionString));
        }
    }
    public ConnectionMultiplexer Connection => this.LazyConnection.Value;
}
```

The class is then injected where needed into dependent classes using Ninject as a singleton

```
           kernel.Bind<RedisConnManager>().To<RedisConnManager>().InSingletonScope();
```

and then consumed as follows

```
 var cache = this.redisConnManager.Connection.GetDatabase();
                key = cachable.GenerateKey();
                RedisValue result = cache.StringGet(key);
```

I've checked that the constructor of the ConnectionManager does not get called more than once

Should we be seeing this many connections?

Comment: Or even better if you use an ioc configure It to create a single instance of it instead of having it as a static prop. It'll make unit testing much easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating the Lazy object each time the `LazyConnection` property is used. This is very wrong.

You should create the Lazy object just once, for example in the constructor:

```
public class RedisConnManager
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public RedisConnManager(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(
                configuration.SessionManagerRedisConnectionString));
    }

    private Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection;

    public ConnectionMultiplexer Connection { get { return lazyConnection.Value; } }
}
```

But again, if you are creating the class multiple times, you will have multiple Lazy objects, ergo multiple connections.
You should probably code it statically:

```
public class RedisConnManager
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public RedisConnManager(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (lazyConnection == null)
            {
                lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => new ConnectionMultiplexer(this.configuration));
            }
        }
    }
    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection;
    private static readonly object locker = new object();
    public ConnectionMultiplexer Connection { get { return lazyConnection.Value; } }
}
```

Now the `lazyConnection` is static, so will be shared across all the instances of the class and will be created just once.
The extra lock mechanism code is to avoid having more than one thread creating the lazy object.

Consider also making the `configuration` field static.

Comment: Looking good, thanks for your help, thought I had implemented this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/ but it clearly works in a different way

Comment: You read article inattentively, because in example they use static property